# How to implement kafka manual offset commits for database transactions

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

I am using kafka, services from dotnet to take messages from kafka, and once I take the message from kafka, I send this message to the database and then performing some operations in the database.

My code works as below..

Dotnet service will execute one method, where i am returning message from kafka.. So here kafka is noting down as that message is consumed by my code.
After this messge is returned, i am performing database operations, so if something is wrong in db, it will not get processed.. But when i retry the process from my service, it will not take the same message, as the message is already noted as consumed in kafka.

So I want to make sure the consumer is committing not after my service return kafka message, but it should note as consumed only after the db operation is performed and all ok.. Then it should make note as consumed in kafka.

Can anyone suggest how can I implement manual offset commits for this case.

Comment: Set property  `enable.auto.commit=false`  and manual execute method consumer.commitAsync()/ commitSync().

Comment: Thanks much Arkadiusz, I already enabled enable. Auto. Commit =false.  I am looking for some suggestions how to implement this consumer. CommitSync() after the database operation.  So, after enabling the above property to false,.. I am running my dotnet code and calling the method to consume messages, i am returni g the messages and offset is not getting changed.. Which is good.  Now i am sending this message to SQL database from my code to performe some operations. But i dont understand how to implement this consumer. CommitAsync() after db operation is performed.

Comment: What’s issue u are facing to call consumer commit after Db operation?

Comment: Your consumer object should have bunch of method commitAsync and commitSync. Just execute one of this.